# How do I stop Hibernate from switching constructor parameters?

Tags: java, hibernate

Say I have three tables in a many-to-many: user, group, and user_in_group. The structure of the many-to-many is:

```
user_id BIGINT
group_id BIGINT
generate_table TINYINT
```

Which should result in:

```
public UserInGroup(UserInGroupId id = new UserInGroupId(user_id, group_id), 
    User user, 
    Group group, 
    boolean generateTable)
```

But instead, it results in:

```
public UserInGroup(UserInGroupId id = new UserInGroupId(user_id, group_id), 
    Group group, 
    User user, 
    boolean generateTable)
```

I thought it might be that the foreign key for group was created before the foreign key for user, but I swapped the foreign keys and it make no difference.

Here is my `UserInGroup.hbm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Aug 1, 2014 10:06:06 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.my.project.UserInGroup" table="user_in_group" catalog="project">
        <composite-id name="id" class="com.my.project.UserInGroupId">
            <key-property name="UserId" type="long">
                <column name="user_id" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="GroupId" type="long">
                <column name="group_id" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="Group" class="com.my.project.Group" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="group_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="User" class="com.my.project.User" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="generateTable" type="boolean">
            <column name="generate_table" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: So the code you are showing is generated by Hiberante? Then where is the definition of the mapping? Do you use XML? Can you show your mapping?

Comment: Is that the UserInGroup.hbm.xml?

Comment: Oh, I should mention that I'm reverse engineering every time I generate code.

Comment: I added the HBM XML that is being generated by reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the properties in the generated constructors corresponds to the order of the properties within the XML Mapping.

In the mapping for the composite key, the userId is first, then the groupId. Hence you get `new UserInGroupId(user_id, group_id)`. For the many-to-one references, it is vice-versa - the reference to the Group is stated first, then the reference to the User.

You can simply change the XML and switch the order of the many-to-one references:

```
<many-to-one name="User" class="com.my.project.User" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
    <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one name="Group" class="com.my.project.Group" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
    <column name="group_id" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

Since the XML is generated from reverse engeneering, the database that you reverse engeneer probably returns the two foreign keys in the order that you see in the generated XML. If you do not want to manually change the XML, you should check, if you can modify the source database to return the columns in your desired order.